# How to display a call from a pixel in the popup of a chrome ext?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to create a chrome ext that works very similar to Ghostry or similar. Where the popup of the chrome ext displays certain network calls.

I would like to display network calls from a certain pixel type, then be able to display items from that call.

I have gone through this https://www.pubnub.com/blog/category/product-updates/

Which doesn't seem to work. I believe this was could be depercated.

I have this

```
// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css"/>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="flex flex-col p-4">
    <main class="main flex-grow">
      <h1 class="text-center font-bold text-xl">HCP365 Debugger</h1>
      <section class="p-4">
        <div id="data"></div>
      </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <button id="getCurrentURL" class="btn w-full drop-shadow bg-purple-500 capitalize outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150 hover:bg-purple-800">get url</button>  
    </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// popup.js

let button = document.getElementById('getCurrentURL');
let dataTest = document.getElementById('data');

// When the button is clicked, get current url from current tab
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  let currentURL = tab.url;
  dataTest.innerHTML = currentURL;
});

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function (request) {
  var parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = request.request.url;

  if (parser.hostname.split('.')[1] == 'pubnub') {
    params = parser.pathname.split('/');

    if (params[1] == 'publish') {
      channel = params[5];
      message = params[7];
    }
  }

  request.getContent(function (body) {
    parsed = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsed);
    dataTest.innerHTML = parsed;
  });
});
```

As a test i have managed to get the currentTabs url via a click of a button, but I would like the display the calls within the popup without a button click. I just want them to be there already.

would this have to be done via `background.js` ?

If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me any pointers that would be great.